# JSF ui:include downside

Tags: jsf, user-interface, include

I have this web application and one of the module use an excessive amount of ui:include.

ex.

page 1.0 include --> page1.1 include page 2.0 include --> page 2.1
page 1.0 include --> page1.2 include page 3.0 include --> page 3.1
page 1.0 include --> page1.3 include page 4.0 include --> page 4.1

and so on..

so in short the landing page of that module has 16 ui:include and almost every ui:include has a another ui:include in it (up to 3 layers).

Now my question is, are there any known performance issue using to much ui:include?

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for this question. Some of the JSF experts (TomEE/openejb committers) informed me that rendered="..." gets called 6 times, so that hinders performance, so I am going through my app and replacing rendered="..." with ui:include src="...". I just finished asking myself this question, and from what I've seen and experienced, ui:include does 'not' hinder performance; a huge page with many components, 'and' many rendered="{EL expression accessing bean attributes}" hinders performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is it has the same performance as just taking all the pages and putting them all together into one page. Since that's what an include does, if you have a page you repeat in other pages, then its just easyer to make one page and include it in the others.

The include just makes the pages easyer to configure and look at i guess

Comment: Thanks for the answer, 

Well the developer who did this is indeed brilliant for making the page more cleaner and reusable. My problem now is how to make this module to load faster, some call are in ajax and sometimes the render attribute of f:ajax can't find the id it suppose to rendered.

Comment: Here my code:
<h:body>
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">
             <h:panelGrid columns="1">
              <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="policyCreateHeaderPanel"styleClass="section1_oneSectionOnly section1">
                <ui:include src="/pcHeader.xhtml" />
              </h:panelGroup>
              <h:panelGroup layout="block" >
                <ui:include src="/piHeader.xhtml" />
          </h:panelGroup>
      <h:panelGroup >
                <ui:include src="/ppDetails.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGroup>
</h:body>'

Comment: Basicly that shouldn't slow down the load of the pages first its gonna add everything thats static and then it will start doing the rest. The loading time is probably because there are alot of components in the pages, and since JSF adds all the components to hidden fields and keeps them on the page even if you don't use them.

Comment: Thanks rafael, we will think of a way to lessen the component inside the page and their sub-pages. I think we have no choice but to re-design this page, :D:D thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If some included components are only shown conditionally, then wrap them in an outputPanel with a rendered attribute that is tied with their display. Something like the following for each include that is conditionally viewed.

```
<a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{myBean.showInclude2}">
    <ui:include src="page2.0.xhtml" />
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

*Assumptions about not all components being needed based on comments in [Rafael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341532/jsf-uiinclude-downside/6341565#6341565)*